# @PostConstruct method runs before flyway

Tags: spring, flyway

I know this kind of question has been asked before.
I have a method which is annotated with @PostConstruct.
The methods assumes that all Flyway scripts have been executed **before** invocation.
It seems that Flyway also uses @PostConstruct annotated methods and that these methods are called **after** my method.
I tried to annotate my method with @DependOn and different flyway beennames.
Unfortunately without success. Can anybody help me.

Comment: There are several ways to intercept in the process of bean creations. You can put `@DependsOn` at class level if you've activated component scanning. You might also consider to user `@Order` annotations or use BeanPostProcessors.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution:**

I would set a dependency on the [`FlywayMigrationInitializer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayMigrationInitializer.java#L26-L27) in the constructor. When the Initializer is created and set up, the migrations are run.

Or you can depend on the `flywayInitializer` bean (`@DependsOn("flywayInitializer")`). The bean is named `flywayInitializer`, of the class `FlywayMigrationInitializer` and it is created in [`FlywayAutoConfiguration.java`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration.java#L208-L212).

`FlywayMigrationInitializer` implements `InitializingBean` and calls the `migrate` method in the `afterPropertiesSet` method.

**Example:**

```
@Component
// @DependsOn("flywayInitializer")
@Slf4j
public class TestPostConstruct {

    public TestPostConstruct(FlywayMigrationInitializer flywayForceInitialization) {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void testPostConstruct() {
      log.info("---->  in testPostConstruct");
    }
}
```

**The Spring Boot log:**

```
INFO 4760 --- [main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Successfully applied 1 migration to schema "PUBLIC" (execution time 00:00.130s)
INFO 4760 --- [main] c.example.flywayinit.TestPostConstruct   : ---->  in testPostConstruct
```

Comment: Thanks. This works fine.
But why doesn't @DependsOn("flywayMigrationInitializer" ) @PostConstruct work?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to use `@PostConstruct` with Flyway migrations - it did not worked, so  `@EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent::class)` worked.
It's not the same annotations but are similar and maybe can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

For new Flyway this work (use Flyway callbacks)

```
    @Configuration
    class FlywayConfig(env: Environment) {
    private val env: Environment

    init {
        this.env = env
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
    fun flyway(dbLoadService: DbLoadService): Flyway {
        return Flyway(
            Flyway.configure()
                .baselineOnMigrate(true)
                .dataSource(
                    env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.url"),
                    env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.username"),
                    env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.password")
                )
                //запуск загрузки из базы после окончания миграции
                .callbacks(FlywayMigrationsCompleteCallback {
                    dbLoadService.loadAllCertificateInformation()
                })
        )
    }


    class FlywayMigrationsCompleteCallback(private val callback: () -> Unit) : Callback {

    override fun supports(event: Event?, context: Context?): Boolean {
        return event == Event.AFTER_MIGRATE
    }

    override fun canHandleInTransaction(event: Event?, context: Context?): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun handle(event: Event?, context: Context?) {
        callback()
    }

    override fun getCallbackName(): String {
        return FlywayMigrationsCompleteCallback::class.simpleName!!
     }
  }

  @Component
  class DbLoadService(private val certificateRepository:CertificateRepository) {
    @Volatile var  certificate: List<Certificate>?=null
    fun loadAllCertificateInformation(){
        val findAll = certificateRepository.findAll()
        runBlocking {
            certificate = findAll.toList()
        }
    }
}
```