# Flyway migration and callbacks (java)

Tags: java, callback, migration, flyway

colleagues! I'm using flyway migration and want to use callback after **my own schema** is created. Is it possible to do it and how?

Answer (score 0):

see my answer, may be it help you [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52127121/postconstruct-method-runs-before-flyway/71034687#71034687)